# airodump-ng not working

Tags: 12.04, monitor, mode

I am a beginner to Linux.
I am having trouble with the command `airodump-ng mon0`. As soon as I do it I see the error:

```
Interface mon0: 
ioctl(SIOCGIFINDEX) failed: No such device.
```

I have tried:

```
iwconfig wlo1 mode Monitor
```

too and the error prompts as

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlo1 ; Operation not supported.
```

[image: terminal screenshot]

Please help I need advice.

p.s I have tried killing network manager.
This is the snapshot.

Comment: Should such `airodump-*` questions be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should kill the processes by using : `kill 709`
Or, you can use: `airmon-ng check kill`.

Second, try `ifconfig` to show some info, then try `iwconfig` to check which interface is active.

Third, try `airodump-ng` interface again.

Good luck!